# Error 13 when trying to authenticate to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, authentication, jdbc

I'm trying to connect to MongoDB through JDBC. The connection string is like below,

```
mongodb://localhost:27017/games?authSource=admin
```

However I'm getting the following trace:

```
{ "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "not authorized on admin to execute command { listDatabases: 1 }", "code" : 13 }
```

My intention is not listing all the databases, but the user has to authenticate against admin database and can read/write on games database. What mistake I'm making here?

I want user X to authenticate against admin DB but read just games DB so not sure why it asks for listDatabase privilege.

Answer (score 0):

First, I assume you are using the [MongoDB Java Driver](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/), which is actually not JDBC.

It would be helpful for you to share:

1. How you created your user
2. The Java code that you are executing
3. The version of mongo-java-driver and MongoDB that you are using

But based on the error, it appears that you are successfully authenticating. I **strongly** suspect that you are either directly calling `listDatabases()` or `listDatabaseNames()`.

The other thing that does not look quite right is the fact that you are specifying `authSource=admin` in your MongoClientURI. But that issue should have given you an Autentication Failed error. You should be either leaving the authSource off of the connection string or specify `authSource=games`.

Based on what you described, when you [created your user](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/create-users/#username-password-authentication), you should have created the user in the `games` database (users will actually be stored in the admin database, but you would be authenticating against the games database).